# Where do INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE fall in the Order of Operations?

Tags: t-sql

On the http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm site I see that the order of operations are:

FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
SELECT
ORDER BY

However, I can't seem to find where INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE fall into the order. Where do INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE fall in the Order of Operations?

Comment: Sequentially at the fundamental level... aka In the order listed. but if you have multiple selects to generate an insert or delete, it follows similar logic to math's ()'s (inside out)  Show an example of one with multiple insert update/delete and we can help.

Answer (score 1):

The link describes the order of operations for SELECT.

INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE is not part of SELECT.